# how to change the button text programmaticaly in iphone

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone development.here i added some list of names in pickerview.the action of pickerview was given to button in view. now i want to show.when click the button pickerview list was displayed i selected one name regarding in pickerview that name was displayed at button in view. I dont no how to change the title in button in iphone.

Can any one plz give me information for my problem.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create a pointer of type `UIButton` as `IBOutlet` in your view controller and than connect that button to the one in `IB`.

when you want to change the name of title just do

`button.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:yourString];`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the title of a UIButton by calling setTitle. Just remember to set it for all the states of the IUIButton. Here is an example:

```
[button setTitle:@"Normal Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Highlighted Title" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: You don't have to set it for all the states, if you just set `UIControlStateNormal`, it will be used for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

declare your button and make property of your button in .h file

```
UIButton *btnl;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnl;
```

and make connection from IB.

Now in .m file,

use this delegate method of you picker

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   btn.text=[yourArrayOfPickerContent objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the custom button title use this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(82,203,129,45);

[button setTitle:@"btnTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can code about UIButton and can set the title to it.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];                               
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 4.0f, 90.0f, 20.0f)];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];                              
UIImage *backgroundView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"];
[btn setBackgroundImage:backgroundView forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"buttonName" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

To change button title,

```
  button.titleLabel.text=@"String";
```

You should Code in the pickerView delegate

`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`